# Delete rows older than 1 month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this Oracle table which I would like to delete rows if they are older than 1 month?

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTS(
  EVENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 )
)
/
```

Also how I can delete rows of the total size of the table is for example 100 MB?

Comment: You have two questions which are quite different.  Please figure out your question and ask it.

Comment: Another alternative is to partition the table by month and then it simply becomes a case of dropping the oldest partition(s) as appropriate.

Comment: I use Oracle 11g XE. I think that partitioning is licensed additionally in Enterprise version.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like

```
DELETE FROM EVENTS
  WHERE EVENT_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1);
```

Best of luck.

### EDIT (see OP's comment below regarding XML)

Without knowing how you're obtaining or using the XML value it's hard to say but perhaps something like

```
DELETE FROM EVENTS
  WHERE EVENT_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, XMLvalue * -1);
```

where XMLvalue is the value you get from the XML.

Best of luck.

Comment: One more question how I can do it using days? But without negative values?

Comment: what do you mean by "using days" and why without negative values? If you want to delete something that happened in the past, you can't get away from using negative numbers to indicate how far in the past you want to go! Maybe you meant you wanted to pass in a specific date to delete before? If so, change the where clause to `where event_date < p_date_datatype_value`

Comment: Because I will use XML to configure the value. It's not looking good if I set value -1 into the XML file.

Comment: really? Does anything actually look good in XML?! *{;-) Why would -1 not look good? And what's preventing you from having the value as positive in the file and simply multiplied by -1 in the database code?

Comment: Can you propose some other alternative solution?